# overriding equals method problems

Tags: java, overriding

I'm trying to make a rational numbers class and override the equals and hash code methods. But my equals is coming back true in cases were its clearly not true ie the numerator and denominator are different. Any idea what could be causing this?

```
public boolean equals(Object rhs) {
    if (this == rhs){
        return true;
    }
    if (rhs == null){
        return false;
    }
    if (!(rhs instanceof Rational)){
        return false;
    }
    Rational other = (Rational) rhs;
    if (denom == other.denom){
        if (num == other.num);{
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the problem (if not a typo):

```
if (num == other.num);{
```

The semicolon means that the `if` statement is an empty statement, so its evaluation doesn't really get involved in the equals validation process. Just remove the semi colon:

```
if (num == other.num){
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon on this line, which is acting as the body for the `if` statement.

```
if (num == other.num);{
```

With the semicolon, if the denominators are equal, then `true` will be returned; the check of the numerators is effectively ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `;` after `if (num == other.num); {`, changint it to `if (num == other.num) {`

Leaving it there, it basically does nothing after the `if`, then enters the block :

```
{
    return true;
}
```

So it will always return true at that point.